# Regex for Markdown style emphasis: with x amount of *

Tags: regex

I'm wanting to write a regular expression for matching strings that are wrapped in * characters, much like markdown which uses them to ****make things bold****.

But I'm wanting to also wanting the number of *'s at the start and end to be a variable amount. The amount of stars will amount to how important that string is.

At the moment I'm using this;

```
/(\*\*\*|\*\*|\*)(.*?)\1/
```

Which works for upto ***three*** either side. This returns both the string between the *'s and the string containing the ***. I then count the length of that string to get the number of *'s.

In ruby, this looks like;

```
"*this is important*, but this is ***very important***.scan(/(\*\*\*|\*\*|\*)(.*?)\1/).each do |match|
    points << { :str => match[1], :importance => match[0].length }
end
```

The regex is working fine in most parts, but if I wanted to get ********something really important********; the expression would get a bit out of hand - doing it the way I have so far.

I understand my current pattern is searching for an amount of *'s and finding the text between that and another occurrence of the same string. But it would also be nice to account for human error, such as a string like;

**This is quite important*, but ***this is really important****.

Thanks all!

Comment: So what do you want the regular expression to do for this case: `**This is quite important*` ?

Comment: What is supposed to happen with `**ac*de**`? Or `**ac*de*`? Is the latter valid, or do we just ignore all `*`'s in the middle?

Comment: I would say matching the amount of *'s in front of the string would be more reliable. Keeping the amount of ending *'s arbitrary. So for `**This is quite important*` I would like it to match `**` and `This is quite important`

Comment: I'd not considered *'s in the middle actually, good point. For my purposes, counting them in error won't be too big of a deal. But I'm unaware of how else it could be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about simply the below?

```
/(\*+)(.*?)\1/
```

`\*+` is one or more `*`'s.

Or, if you want to limit it to a specific amount:

```
/(\*{1,5})(.*?)\1/
```

`\*{1,5}` means anywhere between 1 and 5 `*`'s. You're obviously free to change 1 and 5 as you see fit.

**Different lengths on either side:**

The above will work for the same amount of `*`'s on both sides (because of the back-reference `\1`).

If you want to allow for different amounts on either side, you can use `\*+` instead of `\1`, so:

```
/(\*+)(.*?)\*+/
```

Comment: That looks to work great, thanks. Any idea if I could use something similar in replacement of `\1`? So, match a string between any length of *'s and any length of *'s?

Comment: Between the same lengths or between different lengths? It's already checking for between the same lengths (that's what the back-reference `\1` does). For different lengths, replace the `\1` with `(\*+)` (or `\*+` if you don't need it in a group).

Comment: Actually, this seems to work; `/(\*+)(.*?)(\*+)(.*?)/`. But I'm unsure of the difference between that and your suggestion. Other than mine is longer and harder to read ;)

Comment: For reference, this works perfectly for my needs; `/(\*+)(.*?)\*+/`. Thanks!